# Is the word “etymology” correct when looking for the origins of a phrase?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I wasn't sure, so I looked it up, and it would seem it's specific to single words.

> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/etymology
>
> 1.) the derivation of a word.
>   Synonyms: word origin, word source, derivation, origin.
>
> 2.) a chronological account of the birth and development of a particular word or element of a word, often delineating its spread from one language to another and its evolving changes in form and meaning.
>   Synonyms: word history, word lore, historical development.
>
> 3.) the study of historical linguistic change, especially as manifested in individual words.

Obviously the following sentence would be easily understood, but is it technically correct?  Or is there a better way to ask the following question?

***“What is the etymology of the Baseball term 'meat hand'?”***

As in a first-use, or how the phrase came to be, or what made it popular – etc.  What I think of as “etymology”, but perhaps that word is more technical, and specific to the linguistic breakdown and origins of individual words.

Comment: I think it's usually used for individual words, but it would obviously be understood if you generalized it. I don't think there's a specific word for the origin of phrases.

Comment: Not the best of examples you've chosen.  _Meat hand_ is quite arguably a word just as much as it is a phrase, so whether _etymology_ can be used for phrases or not, it can absolutely be used for _meat hand_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though speaking about the *etymology of a phrase* is a clear and unambiguous way to refer to how the phrase formed and its past and current usage, the term ***[origin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/origin)*** appears to be the one commonly used to specifically refer to a ***phrase***.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=origin%20of%20a%20phrase%2Cetymology%20of%20a%20word%2Corigin%20of%20a%20word%2Cetymology%20of%20a%20phrase%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Corigin%20of%20a%20phrase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cetymology%20of%20a%20word%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Corigin%20of%20a%20word%3B%2Cc0) shows no usage for etymology of a phrase or expression.

- The well known [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/) for instance says:   *1,800 English phrases, sayings, idioms and expressions, with their* ***meanings and origins*** *explained.*